# UDP client is not receiving the message

Tags: c, networking

My [client](http://pastebin.com/v6ias7Tn) program and my [server](http://pastebin.com/J3BuL8Y9) program are as per the link. I am not receiving any message on the client. I have pasted the output [here](http://pastebin.com/v2SHUFhs) . I am getting the multicast address from a configuration file for both server and client. IP address and the port are the same. I tried manual input of the address and port. I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Seeking some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you should check and correct:
1. In your server code, you are not joining yourself to the multicast address.

`struct ip_mreq mreq;
setsockopt(sd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void *) &mreq, sizeof(mreq));`

2. If your client and server are running on different machines on a network, you need to make sure that the switches in between your data path supports multicast.
Switches does a multicast query to find out which hosts are still joined to the multicast address. If they dont do it, your messages will be dropped.
3. Though not sure from the code, but I hope the server port is getting bound to a valid Multicast IP address.

Refer these 2 links for furcther checking:
http://www.it.uom.gr/project/client_server/socket/socket/prog/mcastServer.c 
http://www.it.uom.gr/project/client_server/socket/socket/prog/mcastClient.c

Comment: Thanks. But in this link http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/example.html the server is sending the message. It does not require setsockopt(sd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void *) &mreq, sizeof(mreq)); Even in the mcastClient.c the one sending message is not using IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP. 
In my case I want multiple clients bound to the same multicast ip to receive the message sent by the server. And yes the multicast address I am using is 225.12.13.14 and port 1025. 
Please correct me if I am not wrong, all the clients connected to the group should receive the message right?

Comment: Can you recheck again? I do see it in listener.c

Comment: Client does not require to join to a multicast address, it can bind to your Class A/B/C IP address and send data. Joining is required only for server

Comment: Yes in the link listener is using IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP. I want my listener to be clients. not the server. Would like to know if that is possible.

Comment: Once the message sent by the server is received by the client/clients then I want the client to communicate with the server. Not before that. But the client is not receiving any message in my case.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want. Technically only a server can be a listener. Your server (1 or more instances of it) listens on a multicast address, the client sends a data using normal UDP stuff. This data is received by all instances of the server joined to that multicast address. This is how it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54349/discussion-between-crack-jack-and-arunmu).